# How to remove the default colorschemes from Vim/Neovim?

Tags: colorscheme

The only other answer I found is from 2012, it is not accurate anymore and it is on Stack Overflow.

I would like to see them gone. I don't like any of them and they are clutter.

So, how does one remove the default `colorscheme` in Vim (and Neovim if it happens they're not in the same place)?

Comment: Since you are at it, you can also remove all the ftplugins and syntax scripts and indent scripts for languages you don't use… as well as the hundreds of thousands of unused files that clutter your machine.

Comment: "The only other answer I found is from 2012, it is not accurate anymore and it is on Stack Overflow." for the sake of completeness, a link would have been nice.

Comment: @romainl It's visual clutter in the sense that when I want to change colorschemes I want to only to see the list of the ones I  chose. It's not clutter in absolute sense else I'd be using a magnetic needle and a steady hand.

Comment: It sounds as if this is a question about your particular Linux distribution; you want to change the packages or files installed by that distribution, no?

Comment: @cjs I wouldn't say that, I have tried many distributions and on each one vim had the same colorschemes so they are really vim's default colorschemes I believe. (New and better ones by romainl are coming in by the way)

Comment: @cassepipe Well they probably mostly are, but where they are installed and the best way to remove them without causing troubles with your package system is going to be distribution-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

They are in the `colors` directory of (Neo)Vim's runtime directory.

At least on Ubuntu and Fedora, these directories are

`/usr/share/vim/vim${VIM_VERSION}/colors`

and

`/usr/share/nvim/runtime/colors`

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `colors` folder from wherever the default install location is for your OS. Or actually delete everything in the `colors` folder except for the default colourscheme, otherwise id reckon you'll probably break something

I'm on Windows and I installed Neovim through scoop, so the location for me was `C:\Users\madoka\scoop\apps\neovim\0.9.1\share\nvim\runtime\colors`.